hardhat fork layer2 inconsistency
When testing complex tests with aave and gmx tests often are not consistent, which means I'm forking same block on arbitrum with hardhat and tests results often are not identical, for example when depositing collateral to aave and borrowing, amount of aTokens are not the same on some intermediary result inside the tests. This is probably due to how arbitrum optimisitic rollouts work (or any other layer2) and how they settle on layer 1. Is there any easy technique or feature how to overcome these inconsistencies on layer2 hardhat testing ? Any insights would help. Thank you.
